# Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=c43Mm/zgQbSKm08VSjymaA==)

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

I also started "oracleServiceORCL" also showing Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=c43Mm/zgQbSKm08VSjymaA==)

Comment: Do you have a TCP listener running?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your connection. Check from where your service running. You can either run in command prompt windows: telnet localhost 1521 or run in terminal linux nc -zv localhost 1521. (Assuming your oracle server is localhost and the oracle db default port is 1521). Hope this helps.